# Creating new object in abstract class in Java

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have two objects which use really similar methods, save for one line. For example:

```
public class Cat extends Animal
public class Dog extends Animal
```

And they both use a `breed` method in the abstract class `Animal`. One calls `new Dog()`, and the other `new Cat()`. Right now I just have it declared as `abstract public void breed();` in Animal, but is there a way I can generalize it so I don't have to make it an abstract method to be overridden?

Comment: yes it is not necessary that all the methods in a class need to be abstract

Comment: @SashiKant While true, I don't think that's what the OP was asking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, assuming by `breed` you mean "create children of me."

**Reflection**

First is to use reflection. If you have a no-args constructor for your classes, this is as easy as calling [Class.newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29):

```
public Animal breed() {
    try {
        return (Animal) getClass().newInstance();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO Log me
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you don't have a no-args constructor in all your subclasses, you'll have to have a uniform constructor across all your subclasses. For example, if you have `Cat(int, String)` and `Dog(int, String)`, then you need to get the constructor via [`Class.getConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) and invoke [`newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) on that:

```
return (Animal) getClass().getConstructor(int.class, String.class).newInstance(0, "Unnamed");
```

`int` and `String` here may be age and name, for example. This is how you do this with reflection.

**Providers**

Another way is to use this simple interface:

```
public interface Provider<T> {
    T create();
}
```

Then have your abstract class take an instance of this in its constructor:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    private final Provider<Animal> animalProvider;

    protected Animal( ... , Provider<Animal> animalProvider) {
        // ...
        this.animalProvider = animalProvider;
    }

    public Animal breed() {
        return animalProvider.create();
    }
}
```

Then your subclasses will pass a `Provider<Animal>` to the superclass which will create new instances of the subclass:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog( ... ) {
        super( ... , new DogProvider());
        // ...
    }

    private static class DogProvider implements Provider<Animal> {
        public Animal create() {
            return new Dog( ... );
        }
    }
}
```

Do the same for other subclasses as well.

**Note:** if by `breed` you mean "get the type of me," then you should edit your question to say so. If this is what you meant, then this is a viable solution:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    protected final Breed breed;

    protected Animal( ... , Breed breed) {
        // ...
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public Breed getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }
}
```

I recommend following the `get`/`set` conventions for data container methods. Java has bean classes designed to handle these naming conventions, and it's more or less a standard across many platforms. For your subclasses:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog( ... ) {
        super( ... , new Breed( ... ));
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, yes you can. You need to use reflection so performance could be a little iffy, but this (untested) should work:

```
public abstract class Animal{
    public Animal breed(){
      return getClass().newInstance();
    }
    //other methods
}
```

This will return a new instance of the actual calling type, not the type of Animal (where it's implemented).

This is actually somewhat similar to the [Prototype Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern). Although in this case you're creating a new instance, not copying an existing instance.

**Edit**

As @FrankPavageau pointed out in the comments, rather than masking an exception in the constructor, you can achieve the same result by using

```
public abstract class Animal{
    public Animal breed(){
      return getClass().getConstructor().newInstance();
    }
    //other methods
}
```

Which will wrap any exception thrown in an `InvocationTargetException` which is a bit cleaner and probably easier to debug.  Thanks @FrankPavageau for that suggestion.

Comment: Tried this, but it threw `InstantiationException`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad did it throw it or did it say you needed to catch it?  There are a number of examples of this working around the web.

Comment: Yes, it throws `InstantiationException`. You can try it yourself :)

Comment: If you want to avoid masking an exception thrown in the constructor, `getClass().getConstructor().newInstance()` is better, as it wraps any exception thrown in the constructor in an `InvocationTargetException`, just as when using `invoke()` on a regular method.

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't. You will have to have something like what you have done as below

I think you want to have in your abstract class

```
public abstract Breed getBreed();
```

and then in each sub class have

```
public Breed getBreed() {
    return new DogBreed();
}
```

and a similar one returning cat.

or

Have a protected field in the Animal class called breed. This could then be initialised in each of the subclasses. This would remove the need for an abstract method. For example

```
public abstract class Animal {
    Breed breed;
...
}
```

and then in Dog have

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog() {
        breed = new DogBreed();
    }
}
```

and have something similar to Cat.

It might be worth you while also passing in the breed to the Dog/Cat ctor so that you can create Dog objects of different breeds rather than restricting your model to just one breed of Dog

I am not sure Breed is necessarily modelled correctly in your example. Do you really want new Dog() to be a breed? Or do you mean type? In which case it is just an animal and the abstract method returning animal is the way to go.